# Use ip alias output through vpn

Tags: google-cloud-vpn

I have two vpn with the same provider, both vpn arrive at the same host, as inbound traffic for the second vpn was solved through an alias ip, but now I have the problem to redirect the traffic from output via the ip alias for the second vpn, is this possible?

Comment: Are you using [Google cloud vpn](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn)? 
Also, could you elaborate on how you are using the Alias IP with the cloud vpn and provide any documentation that you have followed to implement your setup ?

Furthermore, it would appreciated if you provide an architectural diagram to better understand how your network is designed.

Comment: Hello thank you very much, Google cloud vpn is used, I share an example of the architecture.   [diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mNoIqQsWrAmj2aIIV4FpHTyGhlfaSO0X/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your project needs further inspection for providing you with recommendation of finding the root cause of the issue and for faster resolution, I would recommend to either open a [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) case or Open an internal ticket with GCP team if you have subscribe any [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support) to your project